# VBA method to see if a cell changed color?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update this short macro I'm using to highlight values in my spreadsheet. Is there a method that exists to check the state of a cell? I want to change back the colors of cells to white if texts gets updated. I don't want to just change every other color in my spread sheet to white that's not a valid case because I have other colors that I want to keep. I just would like to check:

if the color was changed and is not a valid case anymore color the cell back to white...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim itm As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    For Each itm In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)
        If Not IsError(itm) Then
            With itm
                Select Case .Value2
                    Case "GREEN", "green", "Green"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
                    Case "RED", "red", "Red"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
                    Case "Serverely Delayed"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
                    Case "Yellow", "yellow", "Yellow"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
                    Case "Delayed", "delayed"
                        .Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
                    Case "Complete", "complete"
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)

                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You should check Conditional Formating Rules. They do exacty what you need (apply format based on condition)

Comment: I think what Chris is trying to do is monitor changes to cell colors @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Just add a `Case Else`? I'd echo the conditional formatting comment though.

Comment: yes precisely what @Daghan said

Comment: Maybe this can lead you in the right direction, there is no easy way though. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/capturing-cell-color-change-in-vba.574405/

Comment: @Daghan thank you I will check it out!

Comment: `I want to change back the colors of cells to white if texts gets updated.` If the text is not getting updated via formulas then you can use the WorkheetChange Event else you will have to use the Worksheet Calculate evant? Hope I have understood your query correctly?